# System clock synchronization is not working after upgrading to pop_os 21.10

Tags: ntp, pop-os, systemd-timesyncd

I've recently upgraded to pop_os 21.10 from 21.04 and every time I boot my device I get random time/date set on my machine. Automatic date and time under settings is not working.

The following is the output of `timedatectl` :

```
               Local time: Wed 2022-02-23 10:43:32 IST
           Universal time: Wed 2022-02-23 05:13:32 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2019-07-24 03:48:55
                Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

I've tried running `timedatectl set-ntp true` to enable system clock sync but it doesn't work.

Also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1046217/1573526) solution for a similar problem with Ubuntu 18.04 which suggests adding a `@restart` param to `crontab` config but that doesn't work too.

Comment: How off is the clock at start ?  ntpd won't synchronize if the error is to large (the allowance is a few seconds) because ntpd will change the clock advance ie it will quicken or slowing the system clock to get a gradual synchronization.

Comment: start the machine and in bios look on the time - is it UTC ? what should the current value be ? THINK UTC.

Comment: And ntpd is intentionally designed such that it will only change the time gradually to be able to run while the system is doing its normal work. Normal work which could become erroneuos if the clock  suddenly jumps. The normal semantics in UNIX is that the clock should advance continuously so anything which breaks that could upset normal processing.

Answer (score 2):

Because `timedatectl` says that the NTP service is active but the clock is still not synchronized, that means the NTP service is failing to contact any NTP servers, possibly because the service is not fully configured or because a firewall is blocking NTP packets.

The first task would be to figure out the actual name of the synchronization service.

You can find the details in `man systemd-timedated.service`, but basically check directories `/usr/lib/systemd/ntp-units.d/`, `/usr/local/lib/systemd/ntp-units.d/` or `/etc/systemd/ntp-units.d` for files with names with a `.list` extension. Those files will define the name(s) of potential NTP services `timedatectl` could use, and the alphanumerical sorting of the `.list` files will determine their order of preference if there is more than one.

Alternatively, the preference order of services could be defined by an environment variable for the `systemd-timedated.service`. If you run `systemd cat systemd-timedated.service | grep Environment`, you might find a line like

```
Environment=SYSTEMD_TIMEDATED_NTP_SERVICES=<primary NTP service>.service:<1st alternative NTP service>.service:<2nd alternative NTP service>.service
```

or you might find an `EnvironmentFile` reference indicating a file that could define such a variable for the service.

The most common NTP synchronization services would be `chronyd.service`, `ntp.service` (or `ntpd.service` in some distributions) and `systemd-timesyncd.service`, so even if you fail to find anything indicating the order of preference, it's most likely going to be one of those three.

If the service being used for NTP synchronization is `chronyd.service`, then the command for querying its connection status would be `chronyc sources -a -v`.

For `ntp[d].service`, you could use `ntpq -np`.

The outputs of `chronyc sources` and `ntpq -np` are somewhat similar to each other: when NTP synchronization is working correctly, there should be an asterisk in the left-most column of the listing indicating the server this system is currently synchronized to. The `Reach` column will indicate the status of the latest 8 NTP requests as an octal number: if all of those have been responded to by the NTP server, the value in this column will be `377`. A `Reach` value of `0` indicates the server is not reachable.

To query the status of the `systemd-timesyncd.service`, you can use `timedatectl timesync-status`.

Once you know which NTP server(s) the synchronization server is trying to use, you can start troubleshooting connectivity to them. If the list of NTP servers to use is empty or wrong, you should correct it first and restart the synchronization service (or reboot the system).

For `chronyd`, the NTP servers will be listed in `/etc/chrony/chrony.conf` or in `/etc/chrony/sources.d/*.source` files.

For `ntp[d].service`, the configuration file will be `/etc/ntp.conf`.

`systemd-timesyncd.service` has its configuration in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` and/or `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf.d/*.conf` files, but it can also be configured via `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` files or by DHCP configuration information.

If you have the `ntpdate` command installed, its debug mode can be useful in testing connectivity to a NTP server. Run `ntpdate -d <NTP server name or IP address>` and look at the output. If the last line of the output says `no server suitable for synchronization found`, the command failed to contact the NTP server you specified. If the command gets a valid response from the NTP server, the last line of its output will indicate how much the command *would have* adjusted the local system clock if it wasn't in debug mode.

Comment: systemd-timesyncd isnt really comparable to ntpd (it uses SNTP.)

Comment: @StefanSkoglund I agree: it's best to use a full-featured NTP service instead of SNTP-only `systemd-timesyncd.service` if possible.